# How to communicate between WebSocket clients in different deployed nodes on different ports?

Tags: javascript, node.js, kubernetes, websocket

I have a **WebSocket** server and client implemented in **nodejs**, I will create multi-instance from the server using **Kubernetes**, if have 10 instances now from the server node and the clients will connect on it, and I will use the Nginx to distribute the requests of the clients on the server instances, say I have 100 clients connected if each server instance has 10 clients connected, and I want client in first server instance send something to a client in the second server instance how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Redis cluster as an engine of webSocket server, then k8s will look after data availability in any nodes

[Redis Helm chart](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/redis)

Comment: Or more generally, "a database". Redis is easy and simple for small setups. For something bigger, maybe Kafka. And when you get bigger than even that can handle, tools like TCP multicast and giving Cisco infinity dollars.

Comment: @coderanger 
[It is a small setup?](https://centrifugal.github.io/centrifugo/misc/benchmark/)

Comment: Yes, because you will be able to get similar performance with much less resource usage (and thus, cost) with other tools like Kafka, but they would be overkill for a new user :)